# jQuery: Assign class based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery, is it possible to assign a class to an object based on its index?

For example, if I have an `ul` with five list items, how would I assign the class "0" to the first item, "1" to the second item, "2" to the third, item and so on?

This was my first attempt:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(index){
  $(this).addClass(index);
});
```

Comment: Your real problem is that classes can't start with numbers.  Other than that this technique is fine.  Append some text on the front of those classnames and you're good to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But avoid to start class or id with number;

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(index){
  $(this).addClass('at_'+ index);
});
```

Comment: This solution I'm guessing is a little cleaner since the each function is passed in the index, there is no reason to have to reference `$(this)` again.

Answer (score 7):

Bearing in mind that classes can't start with numbers, something like this should do:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("index_"+$(this).index);
});
```

Comment: No problem.  I'd have posted it with my answer if you hadn't beaten me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Class names should not start with numbers. Instead do something like

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(index){
  $(this).addClass("class_"+index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with this:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr('class', 'class'+index);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8JCXD/7/